# Do I need to re initialize longpolling client with new access token on every connection session timeout?

Tags: streaming-api, pushtopic, cometd, sforce.connection

Sample code how I'm initializing LongPollingTransport to create Bayeux client for subscribing pushtopic ,

```
LongPollingTransport transport = new LongPollingTransport(options,
            httpClient) {
                @Override
                protected void customize(Request request) {
                    request.header("Authorization", "OAuth " + accessToken);
                }
    };
```

On every connection session timeout I'm creating new connection and getting access token from it. Now my question is do I need to re initialize the LongPollingTransport as well as it has request parameter having old access token ??

Answer (score 1):

In the case of server timeouts, the client connects again and starts over.

Reference > https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/BayeauxProtocolAndCometD.htm

Comment: Hi Dinesh, Thanks for your response. So according to the link you provided ,we must restart the client and re subscribe to events on session timeout right ??

Comment: One more query , can you exaplain the following which I got from the link you provided ,  "Invalidated client authentication doesn’t include Salesforce session expiration. The Salesforce session never expires in a CometD client. Salesforce keeps extending the timeout interval as long as the client stays connected."

Comment: It states like it will reconnect automatically, May be this example might help you have a look at it 

https://github.com/forcedotcom/EMP-Connector/blob/master/src/main/java/com/salesforce/emp/connector/example/DevLoginExample.java

Comment: I haven't used emp libraries in my solution but anyways thaks for your help.So I will assume that the correct way is to restart the client on session timeout.

Comment: cool! once you done, let me know :)